# Join query with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM orders, products, suppliers 
WHERE product_id=products.id 
  AND `geleverd` = 1  
  AND supplier_id=suppliers.id
```

It works fine except that when the suppliers_id is NULL it is not picking those up. I need that so when a supplier is filled it should get the supplier name and when it is NULL it should also get that line because further on in the code I have `if supplier_id = NULL` place text

This is my suppliers database:
[image]

And this is my orders database:
[image]

So my query needs to show everything where geleverd is 1 no matter if supplier_id is NULL or not

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you want this to happen: ...`AND (supplier_id=suppliers.id OR supplier_id IS NULL)`

Comment: Hi, I think so. What I want is my query needs to show line where geleverd = 1 so in the 2nd picture it needs to show everything. I have an if statement in my code that says `if (supplied_id = NULL) {"supplier not defined"}` but also show the rows where supplier id is filled and than also the supplier with it with the `supplier_id-suppliers.id`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you also want information of suppliers when the `supplier_id` is `null` you just need to and an `OR` condition.

Your query will then look like as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders, products, suppliers 
WHERE product_id=products.id 
    AND `geleverd` = 1  
    AND (supplier_id=suppliers.id OR supplier_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: Great works perfectly. One more question. Maybe you can answer in this thread. Right now I have this if statement `$row['naam'] == NULL ? 'Geen leverancier aangegegeven' : $row['naam']` but for some reason it always shows a supplier even when supplier is NULL why is that?

Comment: Try to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I understand why. IF you look at my output of the query you provided. This is what is going on: https://imgur.com/a/6lh77wj so it shows an supplier(see column naam) even if the supplier_id is null

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code. If `$row['naam']` is `null` then there has to be an other problem since your codition should entere the true clause. Did you make sure that  `$row['naam']`  is acutally `null`?

Comment: I understand why. IF you look at my output of the query you provided. This is what is going on: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/6lh77wj) so it shows an supplier(see column naam) even if the supplier_id is null

Comment: You are aware that there's no `naam`that contains the value `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196704/discussion-between-gentle-sama-and-klaas123).